# Writing R dataframes into a unique file format

Tags: r, format

I am looking for some one who is knowledgeable about both R and file formats/extensions.  I am trying to convert some directions for Excel to an R script.  I start with a file that is .txt and want to end up with a file that is .met.  However, writing the file with the proper extension doesn't necessarily give it the right format.

I think that the .met file is unique to the program I am running (APSIM).  I can google information about other .met files, but they not the same thing.  So, what is a .met file?  Maybe you can tell me, if I tell you how it is created.

To make these files in Excel:

1. Input data (meterological data -- daily temp, rain)
2. Adjust the space of the columns so they are wider than necessary, but not too wide.
3. Save the file as Formatted Text (space delimited)(*.prn) file.
4. Go to the folder and change the file extension to .met
5. Try to use the file, but find the spacing is not exactly right, go back to #1.

[Official Documentation](http://www.apsim.info/Documentation/TrainingManualsandResources/CommonTasksinAPSIM/CreatinganAPSIMmetfileusingExcel.aspx) and [File Format Description](http://www.apsim.info/Documentation/Model,CropandSoil/InfrastuctureandManagementDocumentation/MET.aspx)

Here is what a few lines of your average met file looks like:

```
year          day           radn          maxt          mint          rain
()            ()            (MJ/m^2)      (oC)          (oC)          (mm)
 1985         1        8.2342         -8.3300      -15.0000     1.27
 1985         2        8.5313         -8.3300      -20.5600     0.00
 1985         3        7.1630         -5.5600      -18.3300     0.00
 1985         4        7.6064         2.7800      -12.7800     0.00
 1985         5        7.0866         3.3300      -8.3300     0.00
 1985         6        7.5471         6.1100      -1.6700     0.00
 1985         7        8.7017         3.3300      -3.3300     0.00
 1985         8        7.7457         1.1100      -15.5600     0.00
 1985         9        2.7429         -5.0000      -9.4400     1.78
 1985         10        5.9049         -5.0000      -12.2200     3.81
```

Once I have all of this data made up in dataframes, all I want to do is write them into a format my program will recognize (.met).

Comment: from this, http://www.apsim.info/Documentation/TrainingManualsandResources/CommonTasksinAPSIM/CreatinganAPSIMmetfileusingExcel.aspx, it may not be hard if you know how to calculate those constants (tav, amp) and/or have them.

Comment: Thanks, @Ananta.  I do have all the constants, the issue is just with writing the file.

Comment: Silly question: if you start with a text file and just need wider columns, couldn't you just use `write.table` with `sep = '        '`? (spaces not showing up: use `sep = ' many spaces here' `)

Comment: Uhhh, yeah, @rawr.  I guess all we need are a bunch of spaces.  That works -- `write.table(df, file="this.met", sep = '      ', rownames = FALSE)`.  Write me an answer to accept.

Comment: When I make a real file, I will paste in the header required by APSIM, then write the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description and comments, it seems that a `.met` file simply requires more spaces than normal. This can be achieved simply by

```
write.table(df, file = 'this.met', sep = '     ', 
            rownames = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

where `sep` contains multiple spaces for wider columns. Glad your fix was simple :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this answers your question, you can use all your header here, no need to open separately and work on that.

```
dat<-read.table(text="year          day           radn          maxt          mint          rain
()            ()            (MJ/m^2)      (oC)          (oC)          (mm)
 1985         1        8.2342         -8.3300      -15.0000     1.27
 1985         2        8.5313         -8.3300      -20.5600     0.00
 1985         3        7.1630         -5.5600      -18.3300     0.00
 1985         4        7.6064         2.7800      -12.7800     0.00
 1985         5        7.0866         3.3300      -8.3300     0.00
 1985         6        7.5471         6.1100      -1.6700     0.00
 1985         7        8.7017         3.3300      -3.3300     0.00
 1985         8        7.7457         1.1100      -15.5600     0.00
 1985         9        2.7429         -5.0000      -9.4400     1.78
 1985         10        5.9049         -5.0000      -12.2200     3.81", header=T)

#Now header with constants
latC=5
tavC=5
ampC=5
header=paste0("weather.met.weather
latitude = ",latC," (DECIMAL DEGREES)
tav = ", tavC," (oC) ! annual average ambient temperature
amp = ",ampC," (oC) ! annual amplitude in mean monthly temperature")

write(header, "met.met") #writing header
write.table(dat, "met.met", append=T, sep=paste(rep(" ",5), collapse=""), row.names=F, quote=F) #appending to that, work with how many spaces you need, I used 5 here
```

Adding "row.names=F" make the column number equal to the number of column names

Comment: Thanks, this works very well!  Just didn't accept it because rawr answered the original question first.  Now I am all set to crank out some .met files for APSIM.

Comment: @Nazer, I am OK with not accepting, but I guess this saves you time even more and more streamlined with header already in it.